# When I run my application on my Android Phone from Android Studio, it shows blank screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am building a Chatting App and I am stuck at Sign Up because when I run my application, it shows a blank screen.

By the way, I am using binding.

And when I use this code:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

It shows a blank screen.

And when I use this code:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    }
}
```

It shows an error that: **NewAge Chat keeps stopping**.

activity_sign_up.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SignUpActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/w1"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_favicon"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/chatbackground"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/chatbackground"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/chatbackground"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alreadyHaveAccount"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Already Have An Account"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnGoogle"
            android:text="Google"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/fb_color"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signUpPhone"
        android:text="Sign Up with Phone"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SignUpActivity.java code:

```
package com.agrim.newagechat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.agrim.newagechat.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        binding.getRoot();

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        binding.alreadyHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.agrim.newagechat">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_favicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_favicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NewAgeChat"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have setted the `<intent-filter></intent-filter>` also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set `setContentView()`

You should set like this:

```
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

hare your SignUpActivity you forgot to set ContentView. that's why your screen is blank. You need to do something like this

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also tell me why it says NewAge Chat keeps stopping when I set: setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)

Comment: maybe you do something wrong in your  theme.xml  or any other file. can you share the logcat?

Comment: I have changed this: `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>` to `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey</item>` and `<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>` to `<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/darkGrey</item>` in `themes.xml`.

Comment: it's look like ok. please share your crush log